# The use of $http in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http

I have learnt angularJS for three days,but I have some questions during my study.

well,in the "Run Block":

```
angular.module("techNodeApp",["ngRoute"]).
run(function($window,$rootScope,$http,$location){
     $http({
        url:"/api/validate",
        method:"GET"
  }).success(function(user){
        console.log("success");        
        $rootScope.me=user;
        $location.path("/");
  }).error(function(data){
        console.log("error");
        $location.path("/login");
  });

     $rootScope.logout=function(){
        $http({
         url:"/api/logout",
         method:"GET"
    }).success(function(){
         console.log("I've logged out");
         $rootScope.me=null;
         $location.path("/login");
    })
   }
})
```

In the server(Node.js):

```
app.get("/api/validate",function(req,res){
    console.log("I can hear you FE");     
});

app.get("/ajax/validate",function(req,res){
    var _userId=req.session._userId;
    if(_userId){
        Controllers.findUserById(_userId,function(err,user){
            if(err){
                res.json(401,{msg:err});
            }else{
                res.json(user);
            }
        })
    }else{
        res.json(401,null);
    }
});
```

The first I enter the website I haven't log in,so I thought when the app start run.It must go to the page of "http://localhost:3000/login".But it went to "http://localhost:3000" and it can't print the string "I can hear you FE" in the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your `node.js` app doesn't respond with a `user` when a request is made to `/api/validate`. So in your `angular` app, when that AJAX request succeeds, `user` will be `undefined`.

2) When that request succeeds, you set `$location.path` to `/`. So it will obviously go to `localhost:3000/` and not to `localhost:3000/api/validate`.

3) `$http` makes an AJAX request, it doesn't change the location of browser (URL that browser loads). `$location.path` does that.

4) Currently it should actually display `I can hear you FE` in `node.js` output, unless you have some other problems with your `node.js` configuration or unless you forget to bootstrap your `angular`app (typically with `ng-app` directive in your html).

Comment: I just have edit my node.js code.     when  I get to the page `/api/validate` ,I think it's must go to the page of `/login`. But it doesn't work

Comment: I guess you are really confused about AJAX requests made with `$http`, request paths that `node.js` handle, and `$location.path`. Instead of trying to hack through it to make it work, try to understand how it works.